# Spring Integration - modifying one property of the payload

Tags: spring-integration

In my SI flow I want to modify one property of the payload. At the beginning of the flow I populate a Java bean (let's call it MyFlowBean) and I send it via the difference components of the flow.
At one point I want to alter the property 'extractedValue' of this bean and I want to do it in the right way. I mean I am sure there is a component (a transformer??) where I can say e.g.

```
<transform propert='payload.extractedValue' value='[spEl expression]' />
```

Ok, I know there isn't such a tag in SI, it was just a sample.

Also I could achieve it with serviceActivator but it doesn't seem right to me to write a Java class that contain 2 lines of code and use this class in the service activator.
It has to be more elegant way.

Thanks,
V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Content Enricher`](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/DataEnricher.html) pattern is for your and `respectively` the [`<enricher>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#content-enricher) component is present in the Spring Integration to achieve the desired goal:

```
<enricher>
    <property name="extractedValue" expression="[spEl expression]"/>
</enricher>
```